# Parsing a list of doubles with boost::spirit::qi

Tags: c++, parsing, boost-spirit-qi

I'm getting familiar with boost::spirit and want to parse strings like below:

> double_1 | double_2 | ... | double_n | double_1% | double_2% ... | double_m%

Where m>=0, n>=0.

For example, all lines below should parse ok:

> 91.3 | 44 | 5e-3 | 12% | 11%
>
> 91.3 | 44 | 5e-3
>
> 12% | 11%

I want to use `boost::spirit::qi`.

So, I've written two parsers like below:

```cpp
namespace client
{
    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
    namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;

    template <typename Iterator>
    bool parse_numbers(Iterator& first, Iterator last, std::vector<double>& v)
    {
        using qi::double_;
        using qi::phrase_parse;        
        using ascii::space;

        bool r = phrase_parse(first, last,

            //  Begin grammar
            (
                // double_ % '|'
                double_ >> *('|' >> double_ >> '|')
            )
            ,
            //  End grammar

            space, v);
        return r;
    }
    
    template <typename Iterator>
    bool parse_numbersWithPercents(Iterator& first, Iterator last, std::vector<double>& v)
    {
        using qi::double_;
        using qi::phrase_parse;
        using ascii::space;

        bool r = phrase_parse(first, last,

            //  Begin grammar
            (
                (double_ >> '%') % '|'
            )
            ,
            //  End grammar

            space, v);

        if (first != last) // fail if we did not get a full match
            return false;
        return r;
    }
}
```

And, then, I'm calling them in main like below:

```cpp
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Give me a list of numbers in a format  double_1 | double_2 | ... | double_n | double_1% | double_2% ... | double_m%\n";
    std::cout << "The numbers will be inserted in a vector of numbers\n";
    std::cout << "Type [q or Q] to quit\n\n";

    std::string str;
    while (getline(std::cin, str))
    {
        if (str.empty() || str[0] == 'q' || str[0] == 'Q')
            break;

        std::vector<double> v;
        std::string::iterator begin = str.begin(), end = str.end();
        if (client::parse_numbers(begin, end, v))
        {
            std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
            std::cout << "First Part Parsing succeeded\n";

            for (std::vector<double>::size_type i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
                std::cout << i << ": " << v[i] << std::endl;

            std::cout << "\n-------------------------\n";
            if(begin != end) {
                if('|' == *begin) ++begin;
                if(begin != end) {
                    std::cout << "Parsing second part: " << std::string(begin, end) << std::endl;
                    std::vector<double> v1;
                     if (client::parse_numbersWithPercents(begin, end, v1))
                    {
                        std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
                        std::cout << "Second Part Parsing succeeded\n";

                        for (std::vector<double>::size_type i = 0; i < v1.size(); ++i)
                            std::cout << i << ": " << v1[i] << std::endl;

                        std::cout << "\n-------------------------\n";
                } else {
                    std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
                    std::cout << "Second Part Parsing failed\n";
                    std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
                    
                    if(begin != end) {
                        std::cout << "Remaining part is: " << std::string(begin, end) << std::endl; }
                    }
            }
        }
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
            std::cout << "First Part Parsing failed\n";
            std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
            
            if(begin != end) {
                std::cout << "Remaining part is: " << std::string(begin, end) << std::endl; }
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Bye... :-) \n\n";
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, this method doesn't work correct for corner cases like:

> 91.3 | 44 | 5e-3
>
> 12% | 11%

I'm interested is there another way to do the same in a more simple way using boost library.
Or somehow correct my parsers to do right parsing of above corner cases.
It would be nice to have first and second parts in a separate containers.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @GuyGreer: That will parse things like `1 2 3 4` without any `|` between them.

Comment: Do you want to report incorrect formatting, or do you just want something that will correctly parse correct input?

Comment: @GuyGreer I want to report incorrect formating also.

Comment: @BillLynch above code parses your mentioned string also, but not only that.

Comment: Whoa. This calls for a lot of simplification. Posting in a bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hah. My intuition was this should be enormously simple. However, I've come to conclude that indeed it's a bit nontrivial.

The problem is with making the non-list-repeat separator optional. I thought long and hard about the most elegant way to make it optional and came up with this:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5f2c7f8adf1661ba)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

namespace {
    using double_vec = std::vector<double>;
    using It         = std::string::const_iterator;

    static const qi::rule<It, double_vec(bool percent), qi::blank_type> doubles_
        = (qi::double_ >> (qi::eps(qi::_r1) >> '%' | !qi::lit('%'))) % '|';
}

int main() {
    std::string str;
    while (std::getline(std::cin, str)) {
        It f = str.begin(), l = str.end();

        double_vec v, w;

        bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(f, l, 
                  (doubles_(false) >> -('|' >> doubles_(true))) 
                | qi::attr(double_vec{}) >> doubles_(true),
                qi::blank, v, w);

        if (ok && f == l) {
            std::cout << "Parsed " << v.size() << "/" << w.size() << " elements\n";
        } else {
            std::istringstream iss(str);
            if (iss >> str && (str == "q" || str == "Q"))
                break;
            std::cout << "Invalid input. Remaining '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Which produces the following result given the test inputs:

```
./test <<INPUT
91.3 | 44 | 5e-3 | 12% | 11% 
91.3 | 44 | 5e-3 
12% | 11%
q
INPUT
Parsed 3/2 elements
Parsed 3/0 elements
Parsed 0/2 elements
```

Depending on what you're trying to /actually/ achieve here, things could be more elegant

**UPDATE** In response to the comments, here's how I'd actually improve this by relaxing the grammar. Note how we shift ignoring '|' to the skipper:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7226ed0d0a4b109e)</kbd>**

```
qi::phrase_parse(
        f, l, *(qi::double_>>!qi::lit('%')) >> *(qi::double_>>'%'),
        qi::blank | '|', v, w);
```

Comment: Thanks @sehe. I'm just looking for a simple parser for such strings. What other methods could you suggest?

Comment: I know. I mean, what you are going to do with the results. Is it just about validation? Do you need the vectors per line? Do you want to keep them all? Do you intend to accumulate them? Etc.

Comment: Actually, I have a file with such lines that I need to parse and keep data in some containers, and, then, I'd need to process them.

Comment: @Heghine See, then e.g. [**this** would already be more elegant](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3fd0097cff9f8ca5) (but note that your description still describes 85% of all computer programs...)

Comment: Thanks a lot, @sehe. Another question, what do think what is more preferable in my case - using boost::regex or boost::spirit?

Comment: I'd use spirit, but relax the grammar ([**like this**, e.g.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/498aee9a29159893)), or make the handling of attributes more convenient. I wouldn't see a way in which a regex would be more simple unless you relaxed the grammar anyways. Also, that'd still leave you to do the parsing of the numbers (and you could get it wrong w.r.t. +/-inf, nan etc)

Comment: This is great! Thanks a lot @sehe, Just one comment, expectation operator throws an exception, I'd use '>>' instead, to not put qi::phrase_parse in a try/catch block.

Comment: @Heghine actually that was a typo :)

Comment: Ok @sehe, thats fine :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend doing two passes. The first pass is to apply this grammar. It requires that there be at least one element in the second part.

```
*(double_ >> '|') >> ((double_ >> '%') % '|')
```

If that grammar fails to parse, then we could attempt this other one. At this point, we know that `n == 0`. So we can write a very simple parser that only deals with the first part:

```
double_ % '|'
```

I'll leave a parser that handles the case of `m == 0` and `n == 0` to you.